# The best "negative motivation" movies (or books, etc.)?

Tags: motivation

[Requiem for a Dream](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0180093/) is the best [negative motivation](http://www.stevenaitchison.co.uk/blog/why-reqium-for-a-dream-is-a-motivating-movie/) movie I ever seen. This movie really helped me.

And recently I started to notice that **negative motivation** is the only type of motivation that really helps me.

What other [really good] **negative motivation** movies do you know? Or may be books, something else?

Maybe this question is *off-topic* here. But I really need to know other **negative motivation** movies.

*Sorry for my English*

Comment: This is indeed off topic. I am sorry but this site is not for self-help questions or movie recommendations. Maybe you can ask this on a site about movies like [Movies & TV.SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Damn, my flag queue is full. Am I the only one flaging?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about recommending a movie or a book - this is not a book club.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goodfellas and the Wolf on Wall Street both leave the watcher contemplating the results of the actors bad behaviour. The two movies are highly related; one is about the mob and the other about the market place.

Learning from bad behaviour and seeing it fail is method used in [moral storytelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storytelling) called [conditioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operant_conditioning). Its an old idea that goes all the way back to ancient animal training but was first formally studied by [Pavlov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_conditioning). Negative reinforcement causes people to lose an appetite for evil by seeing the devastating outcomes and punishment so that those behaviours are associated with pain and loss to cause avoidance.

Also worth noting are

- The Great Gatsby (old and new)
- Bruce Almighty
- Click
- Pay it Forward
- Inception
- Oedipus the King
- Romeo and Juliet (West Side Story)
- The Crucible
- Dances with Wolves (Avatar)
- The Necklace
- The Tell-Tale Heart
- Most episodes of Scandal
- The Matrix Revolutions
- Cloud Atlas
- Star Wars: Episode III
- Crouching Tiger, Hidden Dragon
- House of Flying Daggers
- A Beautiful Mind
- Good Will Hunting
- TRON: Legacy
- How to Train Your Dragon 2
- Harry Potter
- The Butterfly Effect movies especially the last one